# RoR3 Devise - Projects per Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am working on very simple application for managing user projects. There are two models, User and Project. User should view only projects they created. So, model Project has user_id column for linking with User. Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :projects, :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When user creates new project, user id should be automatically added to user_id column. This is accomplished in *Project* controller under *create* action:

```
  def create
    params[:project][:user_id] = current_user.id
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    #...
```

This works when I add user_id to params[:project] but I have a feeling this is not a proper way to do is. Or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(params[:project])
    #...
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many_collection_build